# How do I remove the original string when using each_char?

Tags: ruby

My code is:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  str.each_char {|x| print x.next!}
end

LetterChanges("hello")
```

Which returns:

```
 "ifmmp" => "hello"
```

How do I get it to only return `"ifmmp"`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should award a selected answer to whichever one was correct and/or helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"hello".gsub(/./, &:next)
# => "ifmmp"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def LetterChanges(str)
 str.chars.map(&:next).join("")
end

LetterChanges("hello")
# => "ifmmp"
```

or

```
def LetterChanges(str)
 str.size.times{|i| str[i] = str[i].next }
 str
end

LetterChanges("hello")
# => "ifmmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts str;
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: This needs more explanation and context.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
    puts str.chars.map(&:next).join
end
```

but I'd suggest you to refactor it to let `puts` out. This way you don't hardcode the print of the value and you just make it return the string so that the user of the method can do whatever he wants with that value:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
    str.chars.map(&:next).join
end
```

and then you can just do:

```
puts LetterChanges("hello")
# => "ifmmp"
```